resample matlab table based on column
Suppose I have data in a table rawData:



ColA
ColB
ColC




137.326
-92.699
185.085


137.764
-91.964
185.400


138.189
-91.224
185.670


138.382
-90.140
185.985


...
...
...



I need to resample the data based on ColC at intervals of 0.1 and have the values in the other columns interpolated accordingly.
I've tried using resample in various invocations, but all I get are error messages that I don't understand. (Matlab is new to me.)
The documentation has an example for non-uniform data, but I can't seem to make it work.
Any suggestions?

It would be a lot easier for someone to help you if you posted your code and the full error message you're getting.

I purposely didn't include the code, because I'm not sure the approach that I was attempting was valid. In the end I found another way that works, but it requires converting the table to an array, and back again. I'll post that as an answer, in case anyone else is looking for a solution.

In the end, I found a solution that works for what I need. I'm not sure if there's a better way, but this is what I came up with.
% move ColC to front
rawData = movevars(rawData, "ColC", "Before", "ColA");

% convert table to a matrix
rawDataMat = table2array(rawData);

% create desired resampling interval
inc = 0:0.1:360;

% initialize resampled matrix from interval
resampled = inc';

% resample each additional column
resampled(:,2) = interp1(rawDataMat(:,1),rawDataMat(:,2),inc);
resampled(:,3) = interp1(rawDataMat(:,1),rawDataMat(:,3),inc);

% convert back to a table
resampledTbl = array2table(resampled);

% rename table vars
resampledTbl.Properties.VariableNames(1) = "ColC";
resampledTbl.Properties.VariableNames(2) = "ColA";
resampledTbl.Properties.VariableNames(3) = "ColB";

